# Open API specification and App Engine Endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I have developed an API on App Engine using the endpoints-proto-datastore library. At this point I am exploring the use of Swagger to create an Endpoints specification, and am not sure how to proceed. Support for this is indicated in Google's [Endpoints docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/open-api-spec), but there's not much to get started, particularly for Python.

If possible, I'd like to continue using just the endpoints library and webapp rather than going to Flask which seems like overkill. Any hints for how one might thus proceed?